# Manage Token firebase with react js

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

I want to check if the idToken got after a registering an user is still validate butI don't know how.

I try  `const decodedToken = await auth.verifyIdToken(token)`, but auth doesn't have the key verifyIdToken

I installed firebase-admin but my project got failed

Comment: Just a single statement is not enough for us to see what you're doing wrong. Please edit your question to show a [minimal, **complete/standalone** repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem. Just a single statement is not enough for us to see what you're doing wrong. Also see https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Verifying an ID token requires a Firebase Admin SDK, which can only be used in a trusted environment. There is no client-side SDK from Firebase that has an API call to verify an ID token.

The Firebase SDK already decodes the ID token though, and makes that decoded value available to your code. This process is secure and there's no need for you to double-check it in your application code.

If you want to check the claims in the decoded ID token, you can access them from ID token value you can get from the user object/SDK.